# t-sql code: Incorrect syntax at @emp - must declare the scalar variable @handle

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

There are number of errors occurred while executing this code:

> Incorrect syntax at @emp - line 11
>
> must declare the scalar variable @handle -- line 19
>   must declare the scalar variable @handle -- line 32

---

```
/*Delete the selected list  */
use database 

/* create procedure with in scehema */
Create procedure schema.Proc_delete_emp    
                 @emp varchar(50) =0
                 @displayname nvarchar(50)=0
                 @userId int =0
AS 
BEGIN 
    /* Internal variables */ 
    DECLARE @Handle INT  

    @emp =select emp from dbo.emp_list  
    /*definition of emp_list table (userid,emp)*/   

    /* Insert the list  into audit table  */
    INSERT INTO schema.tbl_audit(@emp, @displayname, @UserID)   
    VALUES('emp', CURRENT_USER, system_user) 

    /* Get Handle */ 
    SELECT @Handle = SCOPE_IDENTITY()  -- get handle

    Select handle 
    From schema.tbl_emp_list 
    Where delete_handle = 0 and card_type = 'n'   --/** Normal**/

    /* delete the inserted list from the original table  */
    Delete from dbo.emp_list
    Where pan in (select card_ID from schema.tbl_emp_list ) 

    /* Update table inside the schema */
    Update schema.tbl_emp_list 
    Set delete_handle = @handle 
    Where delete_handle=0 and card_type ='n';
end
```

Comment: What is the problem / issue / challenge?!?!?

Comment: Why have you provided parameters to the SP? You don't use them anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

The first error is clear - this line is invalid:

```
  @emp =select emp from dbo.emp_list
```

You need to use this instead:

```
  SELECT @emp = emp FROM dbo.emp_list
```

Also: since you're storing the result into a single variable, you need to make sure that this `SELECT` statement can only ever return at most 1 row - otherwise you'll get additional errors....

The others are a bit unclear - did you post the *real* script with all its contents? I am almost thinking you might have some `GO` statements in there at some points which you're not showing - that would explain the errors #2 and #3

And also: I believe you need to separate your procedure parameters with a comma - I'm surprised that wouldn't also cause an error... plus: if you define parameters of type `VARCHAR(50)` and `NVARCHAR(50)` - you cannot initialize those to a value of `0` (that's an INT) - you need to use a meaningful value for a string - like `''` (empty string)

Use this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE schema.Proc_delete_emp    
             @emp varchar(50) = '',
             @displayname nvarchar(50) = '',
             @userId INT = 0
```

Furthermore, this `INSERT` statement here is all wrong, too....

```
INSERT INTO schema.tbl_audit(@emp, @displayname, @UserID)   
VALUES('emp', CURRENT_USER, system_user)
```

The `INSERT` statement needs to list the table and column names that it wants to work with - but you cannot define your column names as variables - they need to be spelled out. So change this to something like:

```
INSERT INTO schema.tbl_audit(emp, displayname, UserID)   -- use *your* column names here
VALUES('emp', CURRENT_USER, system_user)
```

Comment: thank you so much ,code  executed

Answer (score 0):

Added to what marc_s has mentioned

you need to keep you stored procedure parameters in brackets

```
CREATE PROCEDURE schema.Proc_delete_emp   (
             @emp varchar(50) = '',
             @displayname nvarchar(50) = '',
             @userId INT = 0
             )
```